# Being Symmetrical in Limit

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits

The question is given $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of symmetrical functions around a constant point $c$. Is it true that the sequence converges to a symmetrical function around $c$?

I think the question can be modified in the following way. define $g_n(x)=f_n(x+c)$. Then $g_n$ will be the sequence of even functions. But still I don't know if this holds that for a sequence of even functions that have a limit, the limit is also even. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sequences of functions do not converge at all.  But supposing $g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)$ exists for every value of $x$, and each $g_n$ is an even function, then the limit $g$ is also an even function.
$$
g(-x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(-x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(x) = g(x).
$$

The two sequences, $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(-x)$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(x)$, are actually both the same sequence of numbers, so the limit has to be the same in both cases.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I mentioned "..But still I don't know if this holds that for a sequence of even functions that have a limit".